# How to link shared library via GNU Autotools

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries, gnu, automake

I'm trying to understand GNU Autools.

My project compiles fine when I add `-lxyz` to the command line `g++ ...`.  `xyz` doesn't support pkg-config.  What line do I need to add to `Makefile.am`? And to which `Makefile.am` do I add it - there is one for each directory?

Answer (score 1):

Add it to LDADD.  See the "Linking" node in the manual.

You can either add it to each program's prog_LDADD, or put it globally in LDADD.  You need to do this in each Makefile.am that links a program that uses this library.